# After upgrading to Ubuntu MATE 18.04, keyboard layout in login screen defaults to US

Tags: upgrade, login, keyboard-layout, mate, 18.04

I have just upgraded from Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS to Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS (via `sudo do-release-upgrade`).

The system UI language is English, but I have a non-US keyboard and selected the corresponding layout when I installed 16.04. Ubuntu MATE 16.04 would use that keyboard layout everywhere (tty, login screen, GUI user session). After the upgrade to 18.04, the login screen has the US layout and I have to select my local layout each time I boot the machine. The GUI user session and the tty (even at the login prompt) use the local layout by default.

How can I change the keyboard layout for the GUI login? Is this a bug in 18.04?

Contents of `/etc/default/keyboard`:

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="de"
XKBVARIANT="legacy"
XKBOPTIONS=""

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and show us what the command `cat /etc/default/keyboard` outputs.

Comment: Done, see above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There does not exist any `de+legacy` keyboard layout variant. I suggest that you open `/etc/default/keyboard` for editing and change the line

```
XKBVARIANT="legacy"
```

to

```
XKBVARIANT=""
```

Hopefully that will make the German layout show up on the login screen.

*Edit:*

Actually `de+legacy` did exist in Ubuntu 16.04, but it was [renamed to `de+deadtilde`](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xkeyboard-config/commit/symbols/de?id=edcc5bfb). So to retain exactly the same keyboard behavior, the line should read:

```
XKBVARIANT="deadtilde"
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Still odd that I would have this non-existent combination in my config, as I never touched that file before. I have another machine to upgrade—I will check the file there before I upgrade and report back.

Comment: I’ve now upgraded the other machine, which already had `XKBVARIANT=""` before the upgrade and did not require intervention afterwards.

Comment: @user149408: My dealing with [bug #1768556](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1768556) was enlightening; please see my edited answer.

Comment: Oh, there’s my bug again (btw, thanks for the quick resolution :-). However, the second machine definitely had the dead tilde behavior pre-upgrade. Apparently, in addition to the rename, the behavior of `de` changed as well.

Comment: @user149408: Was that your bug? ;) Then I'd suspect that "legacy" was set previously in the user specific keyboard settings on the second machine. `/etc/default/keyboard` provides system wide defaults.